# Repairing Corrupted Windows 7 USB/Internet Drivers from Linux Boot

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, drivers

I have a Windows 7 Pro computer for which all drivers (internet, USB, COM) are corrupted or missing. I was able to use a PS2 keyboard to go into to the computer and confirm this.

I then tried the following:

- uninstalling drivers and restarting
- restarting in safe mode, safe mode w/ networking, etc.
- checking for corruption of `ndis.sys`, as suggested here

As of now I've booted into the computer with a light linux USB distro and verified that the hardware is undamaged. I'm running an antivirus scan on the hard drive now and have also taken what information I need from the hard drive.

My question is, short of a fresh windows install, is there anything I can do to repair the Windows drivers from my linux USB boot? Hopefully this would be some kind of linux bash command. Otherwise I would be open to a manual re-installation of all drivers, if possible from linux; I just don't know the first thing about drivers or where they are // where to put new ones when reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux cannot repair Windows and will only damage it much more if you try.
Only use Windows to repair Windows, but you may use Linux for saving your data
to external backup before starting.

I would counsel the following measures, in ascending order of severity
(or desperation) :

- Run `chkdsk C:`, report to us on errors (if any), and we'll decide together if to
  fix the errors with `chkdsk /f C:` or `chkdsk /f /r /x C:`.
  ([chkdsk info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk))
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
  to check Windows integrity.
- [System Restore](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/)
  to a date before the problem happened.
- [Repair Install with In-place Upgrade](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)
- Total re-install, all settings and applications will be lost.